# Make rows immutable and allow insert

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql5

I want to make the rows in a MySQL table immutable, once they are inserted I don't want it to be possible to change them. How can I do this?

(Ideally returning a suitable error message if any change is attempted).

I dont have grant privileges, so I would like to understand how to write `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that raises an error (using signals or issuing a statement that always fails).

I use MySQL v5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A very simple trigger should do it;

```
CREATE TRIGGER stop_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Update not allowed!'
//
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf250). You can add an update to test.

Of course, you may want to do the same for `DELETE`.

EDIT: If you're using a lower MySQL version than 5.5 that added signal, you can limit write by (not quite as cleanly) intentionally causing an error instead;

```
CREATE TRIGGER stop_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE UPDATE_OF_TABLE1_IS_NOT_ALLOWED SET value='Update not allowed!'
//
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4a8a/1). Can't add errors in the DDL and have SQLfiddle save it, so changing the updated id to 1 (an existing row) in the left window will fail the update.

Comment: @user2105729 Yeah, sorry for the naming, will fix that :)

Comment: i tried vut i receive #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Update not allowed!'' at line 3

Comment: thanks, my phpmyadmin seeeeeeeeems to say that i am using mysql 5.1, but i am not sure, is there any command i can issue to check this?

Comment: @user2105729 Type `status` at a mysql prompt and it should show that info.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER stop_update BEFORE UPDATE ON buu_properties_products
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE UPDATE_OF_TABLE1_IS_NOT_ALLOWED SET value='Update not allowed!'

Comment: then i tried to modify a row with my CMS and i was able to modify it. So i dont know why this is happening, i am just a newbie..

Comment: @user2105729 Just verified with my local MySQL, the trigger works in both versions for me. You may want to wait for someone else to answer that has experience with dreamhost.

Comment: it seems to work, please tell me, shall i have to put the table name instead of UPDATE_OF_TABLE1_IS_NOT_ALLOWED or the database name and the table name?? also, is there any way to do this in a column level? meaning to be able to update only some columns?

Comment: To stop with an error, `UPDATE_OF_TABLE1_IS_NOT_ALLOWED` needs to be the name of a table that _does not exist_, and the name preferably chosen to give some idea of what failed since it will show up in the error message.

Comment: any way to do this on column level?

Comment: also, is there any way to prevent update only of rows 1 to 2000?

Comment: Is there a performance penalty to this?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using triggers if you are using InnoDB.

Create another table which is its duplicate.
The columns in new one should have foreign keys (hence the InnoDB requirement in this solution) that points to the columns of the original table in question.

Put a restriction like `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` for each key. Below code for one column:

```
CREATE TABLE original (
     ....
     immutable_column ...
     INDEX index1(immutable_column)
     ....
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE restricter (
     .....
     col1,
     INDEX index2(col1),
     FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES original (immutable_colum) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You do have to manually insert into this new table though.